# Postgres equivalent of mongodb’s facet query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql

Is there a way in Postgres to achieve the same functionality as the $facet query in mongodb? That is to create forks from the results of a query and run different operations in those separate forks.

So say I have a ”stores” table. How do I write a query that first, filters out stores by some general criteria, say we only want stores that are open (let’s assume there’s an open column with Boolean values on the store table). Then from this result returns two sections/groups of stores.

The first section is “most popular”. It contains only stores from the initial result with popularityCount (an integer on the stores table) greater than 5 and they're sorted by popularityCount. The second section would be say “newly added”. This one contains only stores from the initial result that were added in the last 5 days, and of course sorted by createdDate.

So a json representation of the final result would look like:

```
{
   "most popular": [{very old store}, {store a}, {store b}, {store c}],
   "newly added": [{store b}, {store a}, {store c}]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an [aggregate `filter` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) (a conditional aggregate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular aggregates for that, adding an [`order by` clause inside and a `filter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) outside: [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/S3y14sNY)

```
select array_agg(stores order by popularity_count)
          filter(where popularity_count>5) 
          as "most popular"
      ,array_agg(stores order by created_date)
          filter(where now()-'5 days'::interval <= created_date) 
          as "newly added"
from stores where is_open;
```

| most popular | newly added |
| --- | --- |
| {"(2,t,7,2023-10-02)","(3,t,8,2023-11-16)","(4,t,9,1970-01-01)","(9,t,99,2023-10-30)","(5,t,999,-infinity)"} | {"(1,t,2,2023-11-15)","(3,t,8,2023-11-16)"} |

Note that positive and negative `infinity` is a [valid `date` and `timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-VALUES) in PostgreSQL.

With [`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) you can even get the exact json example you showed. Below I'm using its `jsonb` version `to_jsonb()` just to pretty-print with [`jsonb_pretty()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.23.1.1.1):

```
select jsonb_pretty(to_jsonb(payload)) 
from (
    select array_agg(stores order by popularity_count)
              filter(where popularity_count>5) 
              as "most popular"
          ,array_agg(stores order by created_date)
              filter(where now()-'5 days'::interval <= created_date) 
              as "newly added"
    from stores where is_open
) AS payload;
```

| jsonb_pretty |
| --- |
| { "newly added": [ { "id": 1, "is_open": true, "created_date": "2023-11-15", "popularity_count": 2 }, { "id": 3, "is_open": true, "created_date": "2023-11-16", "popularity_count": 8 } ], "most popular": [ { "id": 2, "is_open": true, "created_date": "2023-10-02", "popularity_count": 7 }, { "id": 3, "is_open": true, "created_date": "2023-11-16", "popularity_count": 8 }, { "id": 4, "is_open": true, "created_date": "1970-01-01", "popularity_count": 9 }, { "id": 9, "is_open": true, "created_date": "2023-10-30", "popularity_count": 99 }, { "id": 5, "is_open": true, "created_date": "-infinity", "popularity_count": 999 } ] } |